# AVAssetExportSession halts when app enters background mode

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to combine and a bunch of audio files, and then export them to a single file. It works fine when the app is in active state, but when I leave the app (by pressing home button, going to another app, etc.) it stops completely. When I return back to the app, the progress does not continue, and I have to restart the export. Any ideas on how to let exportSession continue in background mode?

```
self.assetExport = AVAssetExportSession(asset: composition, presetName: AVAssetExportPresetAppleM4A)
self.assetExport?.outputFileType = AVFileTypeAppleM4A
self.assetExport?.outputURL = self.fileDestinationUrl
self.assetExport?.exportAsynchronously(completionHandler: {

    switch self.assetExport!.status {
    case AVAssetExportSessionStatus.failed:
        print("failed \(self.assetExport?.error)")
    case AVAssetExportSessionStatus.cancelled:
        print("cancelled \(self.assetExport?.error)")
    case AVAssetExportSessionStatus.unknown:
        print("unknown\(self.assetExport?.error)")
    case AVAssetExportSessionStatus.waiting:
        print("waiting\(self.assetExport?.error)")
    case AVAssetExportSessionStatus.exporting:
        print("exporting\(self.assetExport?.error)")
    default:
        print("complete")
        self.exportProgress.invalidate()

        completion()
    }

})
```

Comment: First, have you enable background mode capability?

Comment: @MatthewLuiHK How do I do that?

Comment: go to project setting, you will see a tab call capabilities. It contained lot of switch, find background task